# How to use Spring Domain Example + Spring Domain Auditable

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following issue using `Spring Data Domain Example` with an entity that implements `Spring Data Domain Auditable`.

Error :
**org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [Optional.empty] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Optional.empty] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]**

Entity :

```java
import org.springframework.data.domain.Auditable;

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "my_table")
@Builder
public class MyEntity implements Serializable, Auditable<String, Integer, LocalDateTime>

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @Column(name = "my_table_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    // Some fields
    // ...

    // AUDIT
    @Column(name = "my_table_created_by")
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    
    @Column(name = "my_table_created_date")
    @CreatedDate
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    
    @Column(name = "my_table_last_modified_by")
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    
    @Column(name = "my_table_last_modified_date")
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;
    
    @Override
    public boolean isNew()
    {
        return id == null;
    }
    
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCreatedBy()
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(createdBy);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setCreatedBy(@NotNull String createdBy)
    {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
    
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Optional<LocalDateTime> getCreatedDate()
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(createdDate);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setCreatedDate(
            @NotNull
                    LocalDateTime creationDate)
    {
        this.createdDate = creationDate;
    }
    
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Optional<String> getLastModifiedBy()
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(lastModifiedBy);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedBy(@NotNull String lastModifiedBy)
    {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }
    
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Optional<LocalDateTime> getLastModifiedDate()
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(lastModifiedDate);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedDate(@NotNull LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate)
    {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

}
```

Test :

```java
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;

@Test
public void test()
{
    MyEntity entity = MyEntity.builder()
         .someField("someValue")
         .build();

    List<MyEntity> entities = repository.findAll(Example.of(entity));
}
```

I guess it has to do with the `Optional Methods` that I have with `Auditable`, but I don't see how to fix this problem.
It **works** if I duplicate the entity class without `Auditable` but it's **not clean**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix, I don't need to implement `Auditable` since I already use `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)`.